# Building a network with users as nodes and their sentences as targets

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, networkx

I have difficulties in building a network from this dataset

```
Node                Sentence      
Mary              I am here to help. What would you like to talk about?
Mary              What's up? I hope everything is going well in NY. I have always loved NY, the Big Apple!
John              There is the football match, tonight. Let's go to the pub!
Christopher       It is a great news! I am so happy for y'all
Catherine         Do not do that! It is extremely dangerous
Matt              I read that news. I was so happy and grateful it was not you. 
Matt              Yes, I didn't know it. It is such a surprising news! Congratulations!
Sarah             Nothing to add...
Catherine         Finally a beautiful sunny day!!!
Mary Jane         I do not think it will rain. There is the sun. It is a hot day. Very hot!
```

Names should be the nodes in a network. For each node, I should create a link with frequent words within sentence (excluding stopwords) to get the more meaningful relationship.
For removing stopwords from the sentences I am using nlkt (it does not work well, but it should be ok):

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
  
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].str.lower().str.split()
df['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop_words])
```

Then, for the frequency of words, I would first create a vocabulary with all the terms and their corresponding frequency, then I would go back to sentences to create a couple `(word, freq)` where the word is the 'target' node and the `freq` should be the size of the target node.
Here my difficulties are revealed, since this

```
word = df['Sentence'].tolist()
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(word)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
result = pd.DataFrame(word_dist, columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
```

does not show Words and their frequency (I am creating a new dataframe to show them, instead of adding this information in two more columns in my original dataframe; this latter would be preferable).
For building the network, once got the Node, Target and Weight, I would use networkx.

Example of `word_dist` result (not sorted):

```
Word        Frequency
help           8
like          12
news          21
day           8
sunny         17
sun           23
football      12
pub           3
home          14
congratulations  3
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include a small sample dataset for `word_dist` in your question, e.g. using `word_dist.sample(10)`?

Comment: So do you just need a word frequency for each "node"/person's name?

Comment: Yes, chitown88. My goal would be to build a network which visualizes these relationships (which words were used by persons). Probably, rather than using word frequency as node size for the target, it would be better to assign it to the link

Comment: OK, I get it. Your question is: "why don't I get a word frequency list in my pandas dataframe?" No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nltk.FreqDist()` class returns a `collections.counter` object, which is
basically a dictionary. When pandas constructs a dataframe and the first
argument is a dictionary, each key is considered a column, and each value
is expected to be a list of column values. So, as in the example below,
`result` will be an empty dataframe with two columns.

To construct a dataframe with a dictionary, where every key is a row,
you can simply split the dictionary apart in keys and values, like
in the construction of `result2`. The next line sets the name of the
index, if you so desire.

```
import pandas as pd

word_dict = {'help': '8',
 'like': '12',
 'news': '21',
 'day': '8',
 'sunny': '17',
 'sun': '23',
 'football': '12',
 'pub': '3',
 'home': '14',
 'congratulations': '3'}
result = pd.DataFrame(word_dict, columns=('a', 'b'))
result2 = pd.DataFrame(word_dict.values(), index=word_dict.keys(), columns=('Frequency',))
result2.index.rename('Word', inplace=True)
```